# Some questions about Google Data Studio and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am writing a connector for Google Data Studio. I noticed that if I specify in semantics in datashema percent:

```
semantics: {
    conceptType: 'METRIC',
    semanticType: 'PERCENT'
}
```

Then Google Data Studio multiplies the original value by 100. Instead of 2.15%, I get 215%. Can I change this somehow?

And one more question. By default, Google Data Studio for fractional numbers leaves only two decimal places (3.14). I want more (3.1415926). Where can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, Data Studio expects the value for a percent to be a decimal value where 1.0 === 100%. Connectors that return a `PERCENT` should divide the value by 100 if they are returning 2.15% as the value `2.15` . This can also be accomplished through a formula, though the first suggestion would be preferred if you are the connector author.

For your second question, this can be achieved through the "style" tab for a visualization. You might have to scroll, but you should see the option "Decimal Precision" which defaults to "auto". It can be changed to any value from 0 to 8.

[image]

And as a bonus tip, instead of manually defining your schema as JSON, it's suggested to use the [Data Studio Apps Script Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/fields).